# Why is the status of top or htop always "R" (running)?

Tags: linux, process, monitoring, htop

`top` and `htop` are commonly used tools to monitor processes and computer resources, but why is the status of `top` itself always `R` (in the `S` column of the `top`)? For example, here is a screenshot of the `top` command:

```
top - 12:42:33 up  2:48,  1 user,  load average: 0,11, 0,17, 0,17
Tasks: 319 total,   1 running, 318 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1,1 us,  0,1 sy,  0,0 ni, 98,8 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :  15968,5 total,   4031,8 free,   2196,1 used,   9740,7 buff/cache
MiB Swap: 122069,0 total, 122069,0 free,      0,0 used.  13325,4 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   2264 xxxxxx    20   0 2784640 320344 184092 S   6,0   2,0   9:14.83 Web Content
   2195 xxxxxx    20   0 3996144 481160 197788 S   2,7   2,9   7:46.13 firefox
   1704 root      20   0  227712 101204  82140 S   1,3   0,6   3:26.54 Xorg
   2993 xxxxxx    20   0  817416  54452  41724 S   1,0   0,3   0:04.27 gnome-terminal-
   1856 xxxxxx    20   0 4521152 385832 123440 S   0,7   2,4   2:39.79 gnome-shell
   1202 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0,3   0,0   0:52.07 irq/44-nvidia
   5048 xxxxxx    20   0   11980   3888   3132 R   0,3   0,0   0:00.12 top
      1 root      20   0  167972  11864   8480 S   0,0   0,1   0:03.91 systemd
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 kthreadd
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 rcu_gp
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp
      6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H-kblockd
      9 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq
     10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.09 ksoftirqd/0
     11 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:01.49 rcu_sched
     12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.02 migration/0
     13 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 idle_inject/0
```

From the source code of `top` (`procps/top`), it gets process statuses from the file `/proc/<pid>/stat`, while the status of `top`, for most of the time, is `S` (sleeping) if it is continuously printed with the following command:

```
watch -n.1 "cat /proc/<top-pid>/stat | grep -o \"[S|R]\""
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... if you are running `top` (or `htop`), and `top` (or `htop`) gets *its own status* from `/proc/self/stat`... then it *must* be running, otherwise how would it be possible that it got its status while not running? The sole fact that a process is reading its own status means that the status must be running at the time of reading.

You can try this with other programs too, if you want:

```
$ cat /proc/self/stat
32482 (cat) R ...
$ head /proc/self/stat
32491 (head) R ...
$ tail /proc/self/stat
32497 (tail) R ...
$ less /proc/self/stat
32503 (less) R ...
```

Comment: Quite a reasonable explanation on this problem, and how strange I didn't get it previously. Whereas I also met some other processes that have low `%CPU` (e.g. less than 5%), but their statuses are always "R" (Running) . any hints?

Comment: @foool a process can very well spend more time executing kernel code than userspace code. Processes that do many syscalls can still result as running while using few resources (i.e. low CPU%).

Answer (score 1):

This is one example of the so called [observer effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics)) popularized by the physicist [Werner Heisenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werner_Heisenberg): he stated that the act of observing a system inevitably alters its state. Hence, when **top**/**htop** observed their proper state, they can't see themselves sleeping ;-)